# server-side sessions with flask?

Tags: python, flask

I was surprised by the client-side sessions, after trying out Django. What stops the user from replaying old values? When I logout now, my session could be replayed for a month later.

I want to provide CSRF protection (especially for [login and logout](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/62769/must-login-and-logout-action-have-csrf-protection/62797)) with each session. Also, I want to set/unset sessions at the server side, so that old session cookies are not valid. And I want it compatible with the message flashing thing.

What implementation fulfils all three needs?

Comment: As far as Django - sessions are only client-side if you _explicity set it so_ : "It stores data on the server side and abstracts the sending and receiving of cookies. Cookies contain a session ID – not the data itself **(unless you’re using the cookie based backend).**" [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/sessions/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Flask sessions have a built-in expiration date, cryptographically enforced. A client *cannot* replay the session value after the value has expired.

You can set the max age session validity by setting the [`PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME` configuration option](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/config/#builtin-configuration-values). The default is 31 days.

You can set this value way lower; by default Flask refreshes the cookie timestamp on each request, meaning that as long as the user keeps visiting, the cookie keeps being refreshed. Set `PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME` to 1 hour, and the session automatically expires if the user doesn't visit your server for an hour or longer.

If you are curious, sessions are serialised and signed with a `URLSafeTimedSerializer` from the [`itsdangerous` project](http://pythonhosted.org/itsdangerous/).

Note that login information can *use it's own timeout*; don't just record the user name in the session, add the last time you saw that user. The session data is cryptographically signed, so the end-user cannot *alter* the cookie. Each time the user returns, refresh that timestamp. That way you can keep a user login expiration independent of the session expiration.

Comment: as I mentioned in the question, what if I logged out on day 1? The cookie is still "live"

Comment: @aitchnyu: then set `PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME` to a low value.

Comment: Your session store might provide this already; for example a cached backend (not a database), can automatically purge the session. It could be another way to "force" the session out.

Comment: I want the session to be valid for a month, but as soon as I log out, it becomes invalid then. How do I do that, with client-side sessions? And what about CSRF protection?

Comment: @aitchnyu: Set the data you want to be available for a month as a separate cookie; don't overload the session with both time spans.

Comment: In your log out handler, purge the session from your session store; and be careful when you say "client side sessions"; all session mechanism store information on the client, but "client side sessions" means the _session data_ is stored at the client as well. This will lead to problems later as cookies are limited in what they can store.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: The default Flask session implementation *is* a client-side session. This may be limited in space (although the session *does* use gzip compression to stretch that), it is *by far more scalable* than using server-side sessions.